# vbscript regexp - odd number of repetitions

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm using a regexp to clean out formatting control characters from an AutoCAD MTEXT (multi-line) string. In the syntax of an MTEXT string a literal reverse solidus character (`\`) is escaped just like in a Regexp pattern i.e. `\\`, and an example of a formatting control string (in this case to change the font) is as follows:

```
\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
```

What I have been unable to do with my Repexp pattern is differentiate between the following:

```
\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
```

and

```
\\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
```

where the former is controlling format, and the second is just a literal string starting with a reverse solidus.

As I see it in the more general case, I need to be able to differentiate between a string starting with an even number of `\` from an an odd number. To illustrate below, every odd line contains a formatting control string, and every even line is in its entirety a literal string:

```
\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
\\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
\\\\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
\\\\\\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
\\\\\\\\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;
...
```

My best attempt at a regexp pattern so far is:

```
(?:\\\\)*\\f[^;]+?\|[^;]+;
```

but it doesn't work because the first group can simply fail and it will still always match. My thoughts are that a possessive quantifier for the first group, `(?:\\\\)*+`, would resolve the issue, but of course vbscript regexp doesn't have possessive quantifiers.

I appreciate that what I'm trying to do might seem contrived, because who's going to enter `\\fArial Narrow|b0|i0|c0|p18;` as a literal string? But I would still like to know how to achieve this.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you've got nothing to match anything that precedes the string. If you alter your regular expression (which I'll trust to be otherwise correct) to:

```
(^|\b)(?:\\\\)*\\f[^;]+?\|[^;]+;
```

you should get the matches you require; `(^|\b)` matches either the start of the line, or a word boundary. Obviously, if you're aware of any other characters that could precede your pattern they can also be added here.